# WEB Using local map tile cache

Tags: javascript, local-files

I need to show user his own image files, that are located on user's hard drive. (offline map tiles)

```
<img src="file:///D:/1.png">
```

If is launched from loal machine, as d:/1.html, than it's okay;
If from remote as exmample.org/1.html, than image is not found

Answer (score 0):

The url that you use for local files is `file:///d|/mycache/tiles/12/12.png`... assuming you've figured out the other issues about managing the files on the user's drive.

Comment: Nope, this didn't help. Browsers don't see local files, if page is loaded from remote host. Finally have lauched local node servers, which makes that job.

Comment: Good! I wondered about the sandbox. I might also suggest looking at HTML5 local storage, which is a standards based way of caching local resources in a web app.  It gives the user a single page to access, and tools to the developer for handling online/offline use.